# How flux can improve this case

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Please see demo [here](http://jsbin.com/qazebibiwu/edit?js,output).

There are two select, act as filter. Changing main select will change the sub select. When either of them changed, I will send their values to the server, and get the async result.

The problem is when or where do I make the async call. In the demo above, I make async call when I change main select or sub select.

```
onMainSelectChange: function(value) {
  this.setState({
    mainSelectValue: value
  });

  this.onSubSelectChange(this.options[value][0]);
  this.getAsyncResult();
},
```

Because `setState` is async, and I need to send the latest state to the server, I do this in `getAsyncResult`

```
  getAsyncResult: function() {
    var self = this;

    // wait for setState over, so we can get the latest state
    setTimeout(function() {
      var params = self.state.mainSelectValue + self.state.subSelectValue;

      // send params to server, get result
      setTimeout(function() {
        self.setState({
          asyncResult: params + Date.now()
        });
      }, 300);

    }, 20);
  },
```

Using `setTimeout` here feels hacky to me. I wonder if flux can help improve this case.

Comment: When state is changed your component renders again. You shouldn't use setTimeout there instead you need call you async function in render function every time when component is rendered.

Comment: @Errorpro Because my async function will trigger state change again. Calling it in render or componentDidUpdate will cause an infinite loop. To avoid that, I have to check whether mainSelectValue and subSelectValue changed before I call the async function. Whitch can be another issue if I have more than just mainSelect and subSelect.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/miyamo/1/edit?js,output is it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the signature of the method `setState` is actually :

```
void setState(
    function|object nextState,
    [function callback]
)
```

There is an optional callback parameter that will be called when state is set. So you can totally use it to trigger your request to the server. So your piece of code would look like that :

```
onMainSelectChange: function(value) {
    this.setState({
        mainSelectValue: value
    }, this.getAsyncResult.bind(this));

    this.onSubSelectChange(this.options[value][0]);
}
```

And you can then remove your first `setTimeout` call